# css queries for physical scrren size

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Okay have been looking around for about two weeks now, trying to find out how to make media queries react to the physical size of the screen.

But when everyone said that it's not possible, i decided to load in the correct stylesheet but i haven't been able to find a formula that seems to work out the screen dimensions.

So now i'll just ask, is it possible to such a thing for i have a huge TV that's like half a wall but has the same resolution as my PC, but i need the television to use another layout than my computer screen, is that doable?

Just for fun here's some of the things i've tried.

```
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;

var test = document.getElementById("test")
var info = test.getBoundingClientRect()
var pixel = info.width/100;

console.log(width/pixel);
console.log(height/pixel);
```

But that just gave me the css pixel ratio and not the physical, which i hoped to calculate it with the test div being set to 100cm.

```
var div = document.getElementById("test");
var ppi = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(div, null).getPropertyValue('width');
phys = parseFloat(ppi.replace('px', ''));
```

I've also tried this, same problem.

I've tried basing my queries on EM measuring but just like when i tried "device pixel ratio" i find it too restrictive and not accurate enough, and i abandoned pixels immediately for obvious reasons.

And some calm that's it's possible to do this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="tv" href="css/TVStyle.css">` but i haven't been able to find any official indication that it's real or even works while been reliable without having to use some shenanigans.

And now i'm kinda lost for some sources says that it's impossible while others says it is possible, but amounts them some calm it to be inaccurate and/or inconsistent.

So.... how is my project standing?

Comment: Read this, which explains why your measurement attempt failed: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html You somehow need to convince your browser that your TV is a "high-resolution device". Alternatively, and probably simpler, is just to add a toggle button somewhere to switch between the two layouts.

Comment: ... or add a GET parameter when you call the page on your TV, that triggers setting of an additional class on the `html` element, that you can then in turn use to format stuff for the larger screen ... or something like that. Apart from the technical impossibilities, if you only need this for _your_ TV, it doesn't make much sense to invest more time searching for a solution that probably doesn't exist anyway.

Comment: I guess that you could use something like this : https://github.com/barisaydinoglu/Detectizr

Comment: "Detectable device types are: tv (includes smart tv and game console), mobile, tablet, and desktop. Device models of tv, mobile and tablet are being detected."

Comment: Thanks for the help.